# Dúvida sobre endereço na mémoria de ponteiros

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Coloquei um cout dentro do metodo `insertRight` para verificar
os endereços de memoria de `node1` (da propria variavel e nao
do que ela guarda) e para a minha surpresa os endereço mostrados
se repetiam várias vezes, como mostrado abaixo.

```
004FF97C
004FF97C
004FF894
004FF97C
004FF894
004FF7AC
004FF97C
004FF894
004FF7AC
004FF6C4
```

Observem que um dos ponteiros locais possuem o mesmo endereço
em duas chamadas consecutivas a funcao `insertRight`

Por serem ponteiros locais e portanto variaveis locais (Acredito eu, estou certo?)
, eles nao deveriam ser destruidos ao final da execução do método e serem alocados em um outro endereço de memoria na stack em uma futura chamada ?

**Código:**

NodeTree.h

```
class NodeTree
{
public:
    int value;
    NodeTree *right;
    NodeTree *left;

    NodeTree() {
        value = 0;
    }
};
```

---

BinaryTree.h

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include "NodeTree.h"


class BinaryTree
{
public:
    NodeTree * root;
    BinaryTree();
    void insert(int);
    void insertRight(NodeTree *, NodeTree **);
};
```

---

BinaryTree.cpp

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

BinaryTree::BinaryTree() {
    root = NULL;
}

void BinaryTree::insert(int num) {

    NodeTree *node = new NodeTree;
    node->value = num;
    insertRight(node, &root);
}

void BinaryTree::insertRight(NodeTree *node1, NodeTree **root1)
{
    cout << &node1 << endl;

    if (*root1 == NULL) {
        node1->left = NULL;
        node1->right = NULL;
        *root1 = node1;
    }
    else {
        insertRight(node1, &(*root1)->right);
    }
}
```

---

Teste_Ponteiros.cpp

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

int main()
{   
    BinaryTree tree;
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.printInOrder(tree.root);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começando pela primeira afirmação que fez:

> e para a minha surpresa os endereço mostrados se repetiam várias vezes

Isso é esperado para o código que tem, o do `insertRight`, pois sempre que vai fazer uma inserção vai começar na raiz e navega pela direita até apanhar um nulo. Logo vai começar 4 vezes a navegar pela raiz, fazendo com que o nó raiz seja mostrado 4 vezes. Se tivesse colocado um separador visual entre cada inserção como um `\n` teria sido mais fácil de interpretar o resultado.

Veja a impressão que tem, identificando cada nó e cada inserção:

```
004FF97C //insert 1 raiz
004FF97C //insert 2 raiz
004FF894 //insert 2 raiz->direita
004FF97C //insert 3 raiz
004FF894 //insert 3 raiz->direita
004FF7AC //insert 3 raiz->direita->direita
004FF97C //insert 4 raiz
004FF894 //insert 4 raiz->direita
004FF7AC //insert 4 raiz->direita->direita
004FF6C4 //insert 4 raiz->direita->direita->direita
```

Passemos agora à questão que fez mais à frente:

> Por serem ponteiros locais e portanto variaveis locais (Acredito eu, estou certo?) , eles nao deveria ser destruidos ao final da execução do método e terem outros endereços em uma futura chamada ?

Os ponteiros são locais mas o objeto criado não é, e consegue confirmar isso pela criação com o operador `new` que aloca memoria no *heap* e não no *stack*:

```
void BinaryTree::insert(int num) {

    NodeTree *node = new NodeTree;
```

Por isso os objetos são alocados em memória e mantém o mesmo endereço até serem destruídos com o operador `delete`. O ponteiro local `NodeTree *node` que criou é destruído mas o objeto para o qual ele aponta não é, por isso consegue aceder ao mesmo com qualquer outro ponteiro que aponte para o mesmo local.

Inclusivamente você guarda esse ponteiro num campo da sua classe quando faz `*root1 = node1;` dentro da função `insertRight`.

Repare também que se não fosse alocado com o `new` o objeto seria destruído no final da função, mas isso já tornava o seu código incorreto e apresentando comportamento indefinido, e que com azar até podia funcionar. Por isso se vai usar objetos que criou numa função noutro local precisa que os mesmos sejam alocados no *heap* através do `new`.

Comment: Eu fiquei meio confuso. Quer dizer que se um ponteiro local for destruído apos a execuçao do metodo, o proximo ponteiro local que for criado em uma chamada de metodo posterior terá o mesmo endereço de memoria (Nao me refiro ao endereço de memoria que é armazenado como valor, mas o proprio endereço do ponteiro) que o ponteiro anterior ?                                                            Pq a resposta dado pareceu se referir nao ao endereço do proprio ponteiro mas sim ao endereço que ele armazena de um outro elemento

Comment: @Rogi93 "Quer dizer que se um ponteiro local for destruído apos a execuçao do metodo, o proximo ponteiro local que for criado em uma chamada de metodo posterior terá o mesmo endereço de memoria" - À partida não mas não temos como dizer, uma vez que nós não gerimos a atribuição de endereços, e pode acontecer por coincidência, mas não é suposto afetar o nosso código. A reposta refere de facto o endereço que ele armazena e não a variavel em si. É importante perceber que quando faz `NodeTree *node = new NodeTree;` está na verdade a criar duas coisas, que são: 1) Um objeto num local [...]

Comment: [...] em memoria definido pelo alocador do heap 2) Um ponteiro que aponta para esse objeto e por isso recebe o endereço do objeto como seu valor.
No final da função apenas o ponteiro é descartado, ou seja a variavel local. O espaço em memoria que foi alocado permanece inalterado com os dados que la tenha sido colocados

Comment: Por que minha duvida é referente ao endereço do proprio ponteiro, que eh diferente do endereço que ele armazena como valor.

Comment: @Rogi93 Isso é outro pormenor que está a confundir. O que está a imprimir é o endereço de um parâmetro de uma função - `cout << &node1`, em que `node1` é o parâmetro e não uma variável que criou localmente. E esse parâmetro vem de um ponteiro que previamente guardou na árvore com `*root1 = node1` logo os endereços não vão mudar pois ficaram guardados na árvore. Você guardou cada um dos ponteiros na árvore.

Comment: Entendi. No meu caso, eu nunca conseguiria pegar o endereço do proprio ponteiro, pois o endereço retorna sempre sera do argumento passado ao metodo, correto ?

Comment: @Rogi93 Não, você consegue e está a mostrar o endereço do ponteiro, que no caso é o argumento da função. O pormenor pelo qual não muda é porque os ponteiros são armazenados. Imagine que você tem um objeto num endereço e cria um ponteiro para lá. Se agora guardar este ponteiro numa estrutura, toda vez que aceder ao endereço do ponteiro vai dar o mesmo valor pois você armazenou-o. Seria diferente de criar outro ponteiro que apontasse para o mesmo objeto, em que nesse caso a impressão do endereço já iria dar um valor diferente(supostamente, não temos como garantir).

Comment: Uma duvida sobre essa parte:"...O pormenor pelo qual não muda é porque os ponteiros são armazenados" essa comportamento também é valido para um ponteiro que aponta para uma simples váriavel inteira de armazenamento automatico ? Ex: int i = 2 ; int *ptr = &i

Comment: @Rogi93 Sim funciona exatamente da mesma forma se o `ptr` for armazenado numa estrutura, como no seu código. Agora existe uma diferença significativa e séria, que é neste exemplo o `ptr` fica a apontar para um endereço de memoria invalido quando a função terminar, pois o `int i` será liberado no final da função (assumindo que isso é executado dentro de uma função que entretanto termina). No seu exemplo o ponteiro ficava a apontar para algo alocado com `new` e por isso mantinha-se valido mesmo apos a função terminar.